# Browser navigation controls with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularJS application that is using one tpl.html page to navigate and communicate with the backend model. I want to be able to use the browser back/next buttons to navigate within the SPA. Is this possible? I tried history.back(); for the back button but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you will need to use UI Router's state functionality. Below is an example from `Scotch.io`:

```
$stateProvider.state('home.list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
    }
});
```

When the URL changes, browser back and forward will be handled by UI Router.

To learn more, follow this great tutorial: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It does! Thanks a bunch Riten! :)